# substitute word nice to upper case NICE java

Tags: java

I'm sorry if my questions is hard to follow, english is not my main language, hope you guys can tolerate my english. I'm writing a code that read text entered by user and convert certain word to all upper case, for example nice become NICE. The word nice can be combination of lower and upper case, such as Nice NIce NICe NiCE NicE NiCe nICe nicE and such, and in the end of those "nice" will get converted to NICE. Since there are many combination of "nice" word, I set my initial input text to all lower case and replace "nice" with NICE. The problem I have now is I don't know how to print out just the final result, which is all nice word converted to NICE. the program am writing now is doing conversion 1 by 1. which is very long if I have many "nice" words in my string input. Is there a better way to do it? Thank you very much. here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Substitute
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        String search = "nice";

        String sub = "NICE";

        String result = "";

        int i;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String yourSentence;

        System.out.print("enter your text here: ");

        yourSentence = input.nextLine();

        String actualWord = yourSentence.toLowerCase();


        do 
        {

            System.out.println(actualWord);

            i = actualWord.indexOf(search);

            if (i != -1)
            {

                result = actualWord.substring(0,i);

                result = result + sub + actualWord.substring(i + search.length());

                actualWord = result;
            }

        } while (i != -1);


    }
}
```

and this is

```
my output --------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
enter your text here: be nice to your families and be NicE to your friends too. Also be NICe to everyone in this world

be nice to your families and be nice to your friends too. also be nice to everyone in this world

be NICE to your families and be nice to your friends too. also be nice to everyone in this world

be NICE to your families and be NICE to your friends too. also be nice to everyone in this world

be NICE to your families and be NICE to your friends too. also be NICE to everyone in this world

Written by blabla


Process completed.
```

Comment: `I don't know how to print out just the final result` move the line `System.out.println(actualWord);` below the `do/while` loop.

Comment: @Tom. This works like the way I wanted it to be. Thank you very much Tom. I have question though, is it okay to move the **System.out.println(actualWord);** below the **do/while loop?** I thought for **do/while** loop I always have to write the statements at the beginning of the "do" loop then following by the "while" conditional.

Comment: The body of a loop (the code between `{` and `}`) can contain everything that should be executed `x` times (or as long a certain condition is `true`). If you want to print something several time, then write that into the loop body. If you don't want that, then don't write it in there :D. There is no rules that says, that a loop needs a `System.out.println`.

Comment: I see, I just write the code by following example from java website and textbook. Thank you so much for your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

How about `yourSentence.replaceAll("(?i)nice", "NICE");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexes, especially useful when you want to replace multiple things, here a sample for nice, bad and ugly :).

```
String inputText = "your text.....";
Pattern searchPattern = Pattern.compile( "nice|bad|ugly", PATTERN_CASE_INSENSITIVE );
Matcher m = searchPattern.matcher( inputText );
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1).toUpperCase());
}
m.appendTail(sb);
```

Answer (score -2):

This should solve your problem.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
//Convert the Scanner object to a String
String str = input.toString();
//Get the beginning index for "nice"
int begin = str.indexOf("nice");
//Get the ending index for "nice"
int end =  str.indexOf(" ", begin );
//Replace the string between begin and end with NICE
str.replace("nice", "NICE");
```

Comment: We can make a deal: I remove the downvote if you can tell my, why `Convert the Scanner object to a String` is no nonsense.

Comment: I'll even add an upvote, if you explain the benefit of `begin` and `end` ;)